# Spark - Stategy for persisting derived dataframes when parent DF is already persisted

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have not found a clear answer to this question yet, even though there are multiple similar questions in SO.

I don't fill-in all the details for the code below, as the actual transformations are not important for my questions.

```scala
// Adding _corrupt_record to have records that are not valid json
val inputDf = spark.read.schema(someSchema.add("_corrupt_record", StringType)).json(path)
/**
 * The following lazy-persists the DF and does not return a new DF. Since 
 * Spark>=2.3 the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
 * referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
 * (named _corrupt_record by default). Caching is the workaround.
 */
inputDf.persist
val uncorruptedDf = inputDf.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNull)
val corruptedDf = inputDf.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull)

// Doing a count on both derived DFs - corruptedDf will also be output for further investigation
log.info("Not corrupted records: " + uncorruptedDf.count)
log.info("Corrupted records: " + corruptedDf.count)
corruptedDf.write.json(corruptedOutputPath)

// Not corrupted data will be used for some complicated transformations
val finalDf = uncorruptedDf.grouby(...).agg(...)
log.info("Finally chosen records: " + finalDf.count)
finalDf.write.json(outputPath)
```

As you can see, I marked the input dataframe `inputDf` for persistence (see the reason [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-22-to-23)), but never did a `count` on it. Then I derived two dataframes, to both of which I did a `count`.

**Question 1**: When I do `uncorruptedDf.count`, what does it do to the parent dataframe `inputdf`? Does it trigger caching of the whole `inputDf`, the part of it that corresponds to `uncorruptedDf.count`, or nothing? [RDD Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) says that:

> When you persist an RDD, each node stores any partitions of it that it computes in memory **and reuses them in other actions on that dataset (or datasets derived from it)**.

**Question 2**: Does it make sense at this point (before the two `count`) to `persist` the derived dataframes `corruptedDf` and `uncorruptedDf` and unpersist `inputDf`? Since there are two actions happening on each derived dataframe, I would say yes, but I am not sure. If so.. what is the correct place to unpersist the parent DF below? (A), (B), or (C)?

```scala
uncorruptedDf.persist
corruptedDf.persist
// (A) I don't think I should inputDf.unpersist here, since derived DFs are not yet persisted
log.info("Not corrupted records: " + uncorruptedDf.count)
log.info("Corrupted records: " + corruptedDf.count)
// (B) This seems a reasonable place, to free some memory
val finalDf = uncorruptedDf.grouby(...).agg(...)
log.info("Finally chosen records: " + finalDf.count)
finalDf.write.json(outputPath)
// (C) Is there any value from unpersisting here?
```

**Question 3**: Same as previous question but for `finalDf` vs `corruptedDf`. As can be seen I perform two actions on the `finalDf`: `count` and `write`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:
Yes it would persist the inputdf when the first count is called which is uncorrupted.count() but it won't persist any transformation that you do on the inputdf. On next count it won't read the data from the json file but it would read it from the partitions that it cached.

For question 2:
I think you should not persist the inputdf as there is nothing that you gain. Persisting the corrupted and uncorrupted of makes sense as you are performing multiple actions on it. You are just performing transformation on the inputdf to filter corrupt and uncorrupt records and spark is smart enough to combine it as one step during its physical planning stage.To conclude you should not persist inputdf and in that way you do not have to worry about unpersisting it.

For question 3:
You should not persist final dataframe as you are only performing one action on it of writing it to physical path as json file.

PS: don't try to cache/ persist each dataframe as caching itself has performance impact and have to do additional work to keep the data in memory or save to disk based on the storage level that you specify. If there are less transformations and are not complex it better to avoid caching. You can use explain command on the dataframe to see the physical ans logical plans.

Comment: Hi, there are two actions on the final dataframe. How does it affect your answer?

Comment: Just to add that for the inputDf I am forced to persist it by Spark. Otherwise I get the error mentioned.

Comment: As per what i know there is nothing that forces you to persist. If you say that if you persist the dataframe then you don't get error that is weird. There should be something else that might be giving error. What is the error you get if you don persist the dataframe

Comment: What are the two actions on final dataframe ?

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-22-to-23
In the finalDf count() and write()